# Drawing rectangle to canvas in ImageView onDraw

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas

My goal is to create an `ImageView` widget that draws my face over every face it detects.

In order to learn the `FaceDetector` and `ImageView` classes, for now I am simply attempting to draw a white rectangle for every face detected in the `ImageView`'s bitmap.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class ScottView extends ImageView{

private static final int maxFaces = 5;
private static final double eyeWidthfaceWidthRatio = 1.46;
private static final double faceWidthFaceHeightRatio = 1.75;

private Face[] detectedFaces;

public ScottView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ScottView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ScottView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    detectedFaces = new FaceDetector.Face[maxFaces];
    buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap converted = convertTo565(getDrawingCache());

    FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(converted.getWidth(), converted.getHeight(), maxFaces);
    detector.findFaces(converted, detectedFaces);

    PointF point = new PointF();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    RectF rect;

    rect = new RectF(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

private Bitmap convertTo565(final Bitmap origin) {

    if (origin == null) {

        return null;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = origin;

    if (bitmap.getConfig() != Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) {

        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
    }

    if ((bitmap.getWidth() & 0x1) != 0) {

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() & ~0x1,
                                     bitmap.getHeight());
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

}

As you can see, I gave up on covering each face with a rectangle; for now I am simply trying to draw a rectangle in general because that is so challenging for me

I'm not seeing any white rectangles when I go to test this in a test app I made...
Do I need to do something special to the `canvas` after I draw to it?

Also, I am confused on the canvas itself in `onDraw`...does it represent the entire screen or just the image itself?

Comment: Have you tried calling super.onDraw as the first method in, and then simply have a Paint object which has Paint Style STROKE

Comment: I'll try that... what does paint style stroke do?

Comment: It will not fill the whole rectangle.

Also just for the sake of efficiency unless you are playing with video buffers, move your bitmap management code, and allocations outside of ondraw method.

Comment: Nice! Calling super.onDraw() at the start of the method worked!

Comment: Also, where do you suggest I move the bitmap management code? should I move it to a method that is called before `onDraw()` or after?

Comment: Actually it depends upon the application, if you are building a photo viewer app, then I would say, put it in a method, an async task which is called once sometime after the activity or fragment is loaded. If you are building a camera app, then my answer will be to get the framebuffer, process it in native code using jni and call invalidate to draw the imageview.

Comment: hmm interesting. I am thinking more of a photo viewer, so I will look into the `AsyncTask` idea. Thanks for the advice!